# Как приостановить программу в ожидании ввода от пользователя?

Tags: delphi

Пишу парсер яндекса. Есть момент с каптчей. Ловлю его, отображаю страницу с каптчей в `WebBrowser1`.

Как мне заставить программу подождать, пока я введу каптчу, нажму кнопку "каптчу ввел" и тогда она будет продолжать парсить дальше?

- `ShowWessage` останавливает, но не форма становится неактивной;
- `Timer` - не могу настроить почему-то;
- `Sleep` - вешает программу и все-равно не ввести в форму...

Как быть?

Answer (score 1):

Можно вывести модальное окно, в котором капчу вбивать, по кнопке ok капчу подставлять в webbrowser, в соответствующий input.

И если идти дальше, то в эту же форму выводить закэшированную картинку капчи, так работает usdownloader (про webbrowser не уверен, но картинку берут и показывают отдельно, это точно), например, если капча не парсится автоматом...

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, к `GUI` следует относиться как к интерфейсу с пользователем, а не как способу решения задач, т.е. не всегда следует к примеру на `OnClick` вешать ваши основные функции программы.

Почему? Потому что большинство уведомлений (типа `OnClick`) приходят из [*цикла обработки сообщений*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows). В большинстве случаев, такой цикл в программе один. Это основная "артерия" программы, и если ее надолго перекрыть, то весь `GUI` данной программы просто встанет (перестанет реагировать на действия пользователя).

Как же в таком случае решать сложные алгоритмы (многоходовки)? Выделить из кода программы по крайней мере **один рабочий поток** (`TThread`), который будет решать **основную задачу**. Этот поток может спокойно  заснуть, когда надо (`Sleep`), не влияя на работу `GUI`, подождать наступления какого-нибудь события, открытия семафора, освобождения мьютекса (`WaitForSingleObject/WaitForMultiplyObjects`) и может вывести в `GUI` необходимую информацию (см. метод `Synchronize`) для оповещения пользователя.

В самом `GUI` лучше обходиться сигнальными инструментами (без ожидания), типа `SetEvent`, `ReleaseSemaphore` и т.п. По хорошему, `GUI` должен только **известить** рабочий поток о наступлении какого-либо события, например: "пользователь сделал выбор...", "пользователь изменил параметр...", "пользователь что-то сделал!", **но не решать проблемы/задачи, связанные с этим действием**, пусть их решает *рабочий поток*!

**В Вашем случае** из рабочего потока можно просто вызвать какой-то метод через [`TThread.Synchronize`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize). В таком методе можно вызвать любой диалог для приема от пользователя каких-то данных (подтверждение кода капчи, например). Пока будет идти общение с пользователем, поток будет спать. Как только исполнение метода закончится, поток проснется и продолжит свою основную работу с того места, где заснул.